# Add control listview to website in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, listview

I've got a problem when I want add control Listview to my website. I don't see control listview in toolbox. I can't write `"<asp:... "` too. BUT I check and there is System.Web.Extension in my references. Can anyone help me? I'm so frustrated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this ListView:

```
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView
```

Check for this reference:

```
System.Web
```

Then you use ListView in your aspx pages like this:

```
<asp:ListView>....</asp:ListView>
```

Here is the [**ListView Class Reference**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) from msdn for the web control you are looking for.

EDIT: Of course, after making sure you have a reference to System.Web dll, you need to actually use it.

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

Comment: I've got reference System.Web. Where I must put "using System.Web.UI" ? In controller code?

Comment: @Ann Include the references in the aspx.cs (code behind) page of your aspx page.

Comment: @Ann Don't mention it. Good luck!